# Windows 7 doesn't install updates

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, x86

I install all updates and the last one is KB4093118. When I check it to select it for installation, the windows shutdown changes like into shutdown to install updates. These are not really linked that but the shutdown changes without selecting the above as well to install updates at shutdown.

The problem is when I shut down, it says installing 1 of 1 updates but when it reboots, its the same thing all over!

I have rebooted countless times! And even if I select KB409118, it always comes up against in important updates (never gets installed). The previous update seems to be KB4093113 which might be causing this!?

How do I fix this? This is Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: You should uninstall KB409113 then, [download and manually](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=647f49ef-0f0a-49dc-9766-dd255cded1af) install KB409118.  If that still fails include the log file and the reason it did so.

Comment: KB4093113 supersedes KB4093118 by the way, but KB4093113 is a preview patch, which won’t be released until at least next week. If you want the preview patch then install that instead.  **You can’t install KB4093118 then install KB4093113 for obvious reasons.**

Comment: I would love to submit an answer, but I need feedback if anything I have said has been helpful.  Otherwise, I will simply delete my comments, due to them being unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the guys from Microsoft were too smart with the numbering of update packages, because preview patch with fixes for May (KB4093113) has a smaller version than the patch with fixes for April (KB4093118). The Ramhound's solution is fully operational. No need even to download the KB4093118 installation file, it can be installed via Windows Update. To avoid problems in the future, you should temporarily refrain from installing KB4093113.

Answer (score -1):

IF the size of update KB4093118 is 30/31KB you can hide it, if KB4093113 is installed.

Comment: It is 30 KB, what do you mean hide it? What does it mean if the size is 30KB?